# How can I check that each part of expression is separated by a single white space?

Tags: java, expression

I am creating a program and part of the program receives an expression with the following conditions:

- Allowed chars: "1234567890+-*/() " -- **notice the space at the end of them**
- Must be balanced
- Starts and ends with "(" and ")"
- The separation is a single white space between each operator, operand or/and parenthesis:

I have done the first two conditions, but I am stuck with the third one.

Examples:

( 1 + ( ( 22 - 322 ) * 4 / 5 ) )  <<< Valid

( **1+** ( ( 22 - 322 ) * 4 / 5 ) )  <<< Invalid

( 1 + **((** 22 - 322 ) * 4 / 5 ) )  <<< Invalid

( 1 + ( ( 22 - 322 **)*** 4 / 5 ) )  <<< Invalid

Here is what I have done so far:

```
public static boolean isSSWS(String e) {

    boolean valid = false;
    int indexOfWS = 0;
    Character preChar = '\0';
    Character postChar = '\0';

    while(!valid && (indexOfWS < e.length())) {
        indexOfWS = e.indexOf(" ", indexOfWS + 1);
        preChar = e.charAt(indexOfWS - 1);
        postChar = e.charAt(indexOfWS + 1);

        if(preChar == ' ' || postChar == ' ') {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

isSSWS, is **S**eparated with **S**ingle **W**ite **S**pace

indexOfWS, index of white space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited, I didn't notice that numbers shouldn't have spaces. Bit messy, but works for all inputs I've tried.

```
public static boolean isSSWS(String s) {
    boolean isWhiteSpace = false;
    boolean isPreviousCharDigit = false;

    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (!isPreviousCharDigit || !Character.isDigit(c)) {
            if (c == ' ' && !isWhiteSpace) {
                return false;
            }
            if (c != ' ' && isWhiteSpace) {
                return false;
            }
            isWhiteSpace = !isWhiteSpace;
        }
        isPreviousCharDigit = Character.isDigit(c);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isSSWS(String e) {

    for (int i=1; i < e.length() - 1; i++){
        char preChar = e.charAt(i - 1);
        char postChar = e.charAt(i + 1);
        char zchar = e.charAt(i);

        if (zchar == ' ' && (preChar == ' ' || postChar == ' ')){
            return false;
        }

        if (Character.isDigit(zchar)){
            if (!Character.isDigit(preChar) && preChar != ' '){
                return false;
            }
            if (!Character.isDigit(postChar) && postChar != ' '){
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (("+-*/()".indexOf(zchar) != -1) && (preChar != ' ' || postChar != ' ')){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```